# Trying to get return value from program run using execvp, always 0

Tags: return-value, wait, pid, execvp

I'm trying to learn how to correctly use execvp for a project I'm working on where i want to get the return value of another program i run. I've made a short program to try and learn how to get return values, but i'm having no luck.

The program executes another short program i've made, and gets the return value. It always seems to be 0 however no matter what it should really return(this is decided by the argument).

```
  1 #include <unistd.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <stdio.h>
  4 #include <string.h>
  5
  6 int main(void)
  7 {
  8    int ret;
  9    pid_t pid;
 10    char *array[2];
 11    char a[255] = "./program";
 12    char b[255] = "1";
 13    
 14
 15    array[0] = a;
 16    array[1] = b;
 17    
 18
 19    pid = fork();
 20
 21    if(pid == 0)
 22    {
 23       execvp("~/mydirr", array);
 24    }
 25
 26    else
 27    {
 28       wait(pid, &ret, 0);
 29       printf("%d\n", ret);
 30    }
 31    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 32 }
```

Comment: You should be checking to see whether `execvp` returns -1.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it is returning -1. What would be the most likely reason?

Comment: In that case you should check `errno` to see why the call failed - see: [man execvp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)